# Terminus font broken in gVim on Fedora 31

Tags: font, encoding

I have just upgraded to Fedora 31 and see that my gVim with `Terminus 12` font looks like this:

[image]

Resetting the `guifont` option gives me a reasonable looking gVim back. How can I further diagnose this issue?

Just out of interest I have tried the other decent font option for me, `Noto Mono 12`, and got this here:

[image]

The spacing is really odd, and I do not know where it comes from.

The Konsole terminal application can still use the Terminus font just fine. This is simple Vim opened up in the Terminal:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the spacing is actually "wrong" rather it seems the font you selected with `set guifont=Noto\ Mono\ 12` is also loaded incorrectly. I'm experiencing the same problems with Terminus (no character can be displayed), and some other fonts (loaded incorrectly, spacing is completely wrong, glyphs are rendered incorrectly).